SFTP login to MacOS 15 fails with "Message too long"
From Centos 8 linux I need to transfer some files to some MacOS machines.
It works from Linux to MacOS 10.13:
sftp danny@Mac10_13_Machine
The authenticity of host '192.168.2.3 (192.168.2.3)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:SRCu/I2rEqFlhy5Y9zdDHVbrAgzPRMG7Z/6tT9S58UA.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.2.3' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Connected to danny@192.168.2.30.

However, trying the same to a machine recently upgraded to 15.0.1 produces a strange error message:
$ sftp danny@Mac_15_Machine
Password:
Received message too long 778199411

I checked with WireShark and there is no huge packet being sent on the network, but because it is encrypted with SSH I can't really debug further.
Anybody get the sftp server working properly on MacOS 15?
EDIT I
Indeed, as suggested below, bash on MacOS 15 prints some stuff upon login:
$ ssh danny@xx.xx.xx.xx
Password:
Last login: Wed Oct  9 09:18:06 2024

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

So it is Apple printing the messages on ssh login.  I don't want to switch to zsh. I searched through ~/.bash* and /etc/bash* but didn't find anything that was printing that message.  Anyone know how to disable it?

Add the -vvv option to the sftp command to get a highly verbose trace of what's going on as it tries to connect.


Put simply, .bashrc, .bash_profile, .cshrc, .profile, etc., [on the server] have to be silent for non-interactive sessions or they interfere with the sftp / scp connection protocol.

sftp gives an error: "Received message too long" and what is the reason? (unix.stackexchange.com)
If the SFTP server is a late-model Mac, the target user has the built-in BASH as the default shell, and you don't want to change it, run this as that user:
echo export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1 >> ~/.bash_profile

Be aware that BASH is deprecated and outdated, and will eventually be removed in a future version of macOS.

That was it!  Apple added some extra messages in the upgrade.  How can I disable the messages?

See my updated answer.

Thanks.  It worked after putting that line in .bash_profile. Update your answer and I'll mark as accepted.
